# Reinstall system using deja dup back-up from maintenance mode

Tags: 13.04, backup, 13.10, deja-dup

Well the upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 failed, seemingly because it couldn't install 'tex-common'! I'll file a bug report later, but in the mean time I'm stuck in a maintenance shell:

```
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
Filesystem check or mount failed.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re-trying
filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored
root@ComputerName:~#
```

I backed up my system before attempting the installation using the default backup software (which I believe is called deja dup). How can I reinstall my 13.04 system from the back up which is on an external usb hard drive?

Thanks.

My laptop is a System76 Galago Ultrapro.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is no way to boot ubuntu from the deja dup backup.

I had to create a bootable Ubuntu usb drive (my laptop does not have a dvd drive). Since my laptop was incapacitated I had to do this on my old macbook, following the instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Then I booted from that usb drive, and instructed it to re-install Ubuntu 13.10. It apparently recognised that 13.10 had previously been installed, and all of my files where apparently still in place (no need to restore from the backup).